# text node ignored if present b/w html and head node?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom

Why doesn't text node(spaces) come if we try to get firstChild node of HTMLhtmlElement?

In the attached image, there are some spaces between `<html>` and `<head>` tag and ideally firstChild Node object of html node should be text node instead of head node.

Is there any know bug?

I tried it in Chrome.

**Note:** spaces b/w head and body is properly reflected in dom traversal api call, for example nextSibling of head is Text node in this example.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the content model of the [`html` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/semantics.html#the-html-element) doesn't allow text, so any whitespace there can be completely ignored by the parser.

Contrast this with the content model of (say) the [`body` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-body-element), which is [Flow Content](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#flow-content-1), which lists (amongst other things) [text](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#text-content). Although I expect you'll find that leading whitespace after `<body>` and before another tag (say, `<p>`) will also be left out. I expect that's covered by one of the dozens of parsing states described in [§8.2](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#parsing).